# How to point GoDaddy domain name to EC2 free tier instance without additional costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've a domain name registered with GoDaddy and would like to point it to free tier EC2 instance.

Googling for this query, most of the solutions asks for the below 2 options which involves money

1. Amazon Route 53
2. Elastic IP address

Is there a simpler way to point domain to public IP address of EC2 ?

Comment: Perhaps better asked at devops SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an '**A**' record in the Godaddy domain control panel,  pointing to the public IP address of the EC2 instance. As long as you don't stop or terminate the ec2 instance, the ipaddress will not change. Elastic IPs are tied to an account, not an instance. Read more in the links given below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html